# Which of the following sentences is the correct usage of the question?

Tags: expressions, american-english

Which of the following sentences is the correct usage of the question or most commonly used in the conversational context?

Was the rental equipment returned today?

Has the rental equipment been returned today?

Did the rental equipment come back today?

If none of the above is used correctly, how should I put it in the right way?

Answer (score 0):

These all are correct.  I would favor the first and third  expressions as more natural, but the second is not at all  wrong.

Comment: I see the question is tagged 'American English', but, for the record, in BrE the second would be the most natural.